# How to get rid of Filezilla connection timeout?

Tags: networking, ssh, ftp, connection, filezilla

I have a problem with connecting to server with filezilla. First of all it sometimes can connect to the server but then I can't browser files because of the timeout error (adding more time doesn't help and I can browse normally in terminal with ssh).

I have no idea how to fix this. I tried multiple solutions on configuration wizard (default transfer mode, different ports, getting the externel ip) but none helped. Summary says

> Connection closed prematurely
>   Please ensure you have a stable internet connection and carefully check your settings again
>   If the problem persists, some router and/or firewall keeps interrupting the connection.

How is it then that connecting with ssh works?

Have you guys any idea what might be wrong or is there another gui than filezilla on linux for ftp which would make things little easier than use terminal commands?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this as well?

Edit -> Settings -> Connection -> FTP -> Send FTP keep-alive commands

Comment: Thanks, I did this but the server still keeps disconnecting. I switched to a new ISP, it was not like this before so I think it is not the server but the internet connection settings of the ISP?